# Where to buy interior parts, that OEM doesn't sell?

Tags: nissan, parts

I am trying to find an armrest cushion in Altima 2008 ([this part](http://vvcap.net/db/TIKFLbFagJgK0vvvmGQz.htp)). But Nissan and all OEM re-sellers will not sell the cushion only, they are only selling it as a whole door panel, which is very expensive and I don't need it.

Is there any alternative place, where I could get that part, original quality, and reasonably priced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to pick n pull type junkyards you may also want to look for online forums for Nissan enthusiasts. I am afraid I'm only familiar with the Subaru community, but it is quite common to find original interior parts for sale by members who part out entire vehicles for various reasons.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a reasonable price and original (used) quality, I would try a pick 'n' pull type of place.  Are you sure that the armrest is made to come off of the door panel?  There may be a reason they only sell the door panel ...

Answer (score 3):

You might try taking some doughnuts down to the local dealer parts department to see if there isn't another part number for just the cushion, even if it's from a different year or model.  If not, if you want the factory part, it sounds like you're going to have to go to the boneyard.  I've had good luck at Pick-n-Pull, sometimes they have vehicles with the interior intact and in decent shape.  Apart from that, if you have a cushion and it's just damaged, maybe an auto upholstery shop can fix it up for you.  They can sometimes find a pretty good match for the factory material.

Answer (score 2):

I am from a nissan dealer. Parts guy even! Haha I just looked up in my system for an 08 altima and I'm not seeing armrests other than on the doors and middle section of the rear seats. Part number 88700-JA02A, 88700-JA02B, or 88700-JA02C (more than likely going to be dependant on interior color) for production year 05/07 - 07/08. Other than that I come up with the built in armrests in the doors. So which arm rests do you refer to? Or do you mean the lid for the Centre console?

Comment: Welcome to the site, it's great to see such contributions! Bear in mind that questions seeking clarification should be addressed as comments to the question.